# will pointer to a variable in the map be invalidated?

Tags: c++

I have something in my codes:

```
class Foo {
// something
};

std::unordered_map<int, Foo> foo_map;
// some insertion on the map

auto iter = foo_map.find(1);
auto foo = &iter->second;  //assume iter!=foo_map.end()
// a lot of operation on the map, may need the rehashing....
```

So my question is whether the pointer foo is still invalid or not after all this operations?

Comment: `foo` is not a pointer; it's a copy of a `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly, iterators in unordered_map remain valid after insertion/deletion. The only exception being when the growth of the container forces a rehash.

References/pointers to elements remain valid in all cases, even after a rehash.

Comment: References remain valid unless of course element to which a reference points is removed. For example `foo_map.insert(1, x)` would invalidate `foo`, because the original element with the key `1` is replaced by a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) for `unordered_map`:

> References and pointers to either key or data stored in the container
>   are only invalidated by erasing that element, even when the
>   corresponding iterator is invalidated.